# Display configuration messed up

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, monitor

I have a laptop and an external monitor. I can set the correct resolution for both of them, however, after some time configuration messes up: resolutions get swapped and display mirroring turns on. What can I do to stop this behavior?

Comment: by some time, do you mean several reboots?

Answer (score 0):

Normally "after-some-time-problems" are related to heat issues. I would try to test your graphic card for hardware failure. You can boot windows or a live CD and see if you get the same problems. If it is the case than probably your laptop is broken.